# Brackets Editor and Mac Localhost

Tags: php, localhost, hard-drive, adobe-brackets

I'm using Brackets and would like to be able to use the "Live Preview" feature with .php files. All my site folders and files that I work on are stored on an external hard drive. Is this possible? I have confirmed that Apache is running on my computer. When I go to: http://localhost I get the "It works!" message. However, I am not able figure out the path to files on an external drive. For instance, I have a folder name "ian" in a folder named "Web Sites" in a folder named "Steve Documents" on a drive named "Vence." But, when I try this path it doesn't work:

http://localhost/Volumes/Vence/Steve%20Documents/Web%20Sites/ian/

Any help or guidance in how to create the path successfully would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with Brackets built in server; however, Brackets does allow you to use your own backend. This will be a little more complicated to setup, but it should do what you want.

Source https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#live-preview